# convert byte stream of various unicodes to a single UTF8 String

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8, utf-16

Has any one stumbled across a great java utility to convert a stream of bytes of various unicodes into an UTF8 String?

The problem I have to solve is I get data in byte streams, lets say its html, that contains UTF8, UTF-16LE, UTF-16BE, and in all languages and what I would like is to normalize this to a single string of UTF8. It also should be very fast but I would like to find something that worked well at a minimum.

Also the different encodings can be anywhere within the stream. That is to say that its random in nature. It does not have to be html, it can be anything, literally.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Common Utils API will solve your requirement.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/StringUtils.html

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html

Comment: Sadly these provide no value. These still require you know what the charset is is for each and every byte. The problem is you have a blob of bytes with random, intermixed charsets which is the real problem. I'm afraid it can only be done brute force. Thanks.